# SSRS graph expression - custom week filter/expression

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I’ve got a graph in SSRS, and as you can see in the picture below, there’s no data before week 47. To make my graph more visually appealing, I would like to put a filter on it to ensure that its starting point is week 47. I’ve attempted to put a filter on my graph (picture attached below). The problem is that if I set my week filter to **>=47** then my graph won’t show any data from **2019**, as the starting point for 2019 is **week 1** which is obviously less than 47. Does anybody know what filter/expression I should use in order to make sure that starting point is week 47 without cutting off any data from 2019?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to stick the fields Year and Week to be in "YYYYWW" format (by adding a calculated field in Dataset directly in Reporting Services, for example) and filter the graph by [Year_Week] >= 201847.

The calculated field [Year_Week] will be an integer and calculated like in example below (assuming that you have separated integer fields [Year] and [Week], so if this is not the case then the formula may differ from mine):

```
=CInt(CStr(Fields!Year.Value) & Right("00" & CStr(Fields!Week.Value), 2))
```

[This image shows how my calendar table looks like with the new calculated field Year_Week which now can be used for filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh57D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do it:

```
[Week]>=47 OR [YEAR]>=2019
```